# In the Harry Potter universe, Is it possible to cast one spell whilst saying the incantation of a different spell?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Imagine a wizard trainee, who is told that the word "expelliarmus" is in fact the "avada kedavra" spell. Would he actually cast "avada kedavra" or "expelliarmus".

In other words can you think of one spell, think another and actually cast the thought spell instead of the spoken one.

This would be a major advantage, if you can do it and I wonder why everyone prefers the unspoken one.

EDIT: to be clear i dont ask for two spells at the same time, but casting another spell than you have spoken.

Comment: As is, this question is unclear. It's impossible to cast two spells at the same time. I'm also not sure how you would *think* one spell and *say* another. Spells require concentration. Or is the question about how easy it is to pick up new spells, whether new students can perform spells just by saying the words?

Comment: Coming to the aid of the the new guy, he is asking whether a wizard can say the name of one spell and cast another (the first of course being a bluff), in this case the wizard is saying Expelliarmus but casts Avada Kedavra (thinking and wanting to kill) while confusing the enemy and having a big advantage over them. @TheDarkLord

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin If someone casts AK at you the fact that they've said the name of a different spell will be the least of your worries. I'm not sure whether that was actually what the questioner was asking, by the way.

Comment: "In other words can you think of one spell, think another and actually cast the thougtthought spell instead of the spoken one. " He kind of does ask that. @TheDarkLord

Comment: @The Dark Lord see my Edit of the question.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin So 'Is it possible to cast one spell whilst saying the incantation of a different spell?' might be a clearer title? The wording is not at all clear so I'm not 100%. In my view that question shouldn't be closed for being opinion-based.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - From what I understand from this question, yes that would be a better title. And has almost no reason to be closed as dupe since that question has nothing to do with this one.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin That question's accepted answer answers the question "what would happen if you think one thing and say another," which I believe is what this question is going for.

Comment: Just read the question not the answer as well, my mistake here.

Comment: The answer to the other question doesn’t really address this one. Moreover, applying the Shog9 rule, not every good answer to the other question would answer this one.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misunderstood the question. The other one is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: No its not possible. Since we see many accidents or spells not working when pronounced wrongly, it means unless the spell is spoken correctly, even if you think it right in your head it wont work. In that case, since the spell is not affected by any verbal magic, non verbal spells may be more focused on the thought of the spell rather than the pronunciation. Perfect example is even though ron has total focus, his wingardium spell doesnt work because he spelt it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer to this question is most easily shown in the first book. In the instance where Hermione corrects Ron for his incorrect pronunciation of "wingardium leviosa," the necessity of the speaking portion of the spell is clearly shown. Even if the wand movement was that of a certain spell, the incantation must also match, or else the spell will be ineffective.